# Get parent with child reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know if I have to access all the children with class `child` of parent with class `parent` we write

```
$('.parent .child')
```

But I don't know how to access parents with class `parent` of child with class `child`.

My situation is, I want to color all divs with class `lmn` red who are immediate previous element with class `abc` and `.abc` has an element with class `pqr`. My mark up becomes

```
<div class='lmn'>                
    Prev of 1
</div>
<div class='abc'>
    1 - 1
    <div class='xyz'></div>
</div>
<div class='abc'>
1 - 2
    <div class='pqr'></div>
</div>
<div class='lmn'>
    Prev of 2
</div>
<div class='abc'>
    2 - 1
    <div class='xyz'></div>
</div>
<div class='abc'>
    2 - 2
    <div class='pqr'></div>
</div>
```

and jquery

```
$(".pqr").closests('.abc').prevAll(".lmn:first").css("color", "red");
```

but it is making only first div `vlmn` red, even though both divs `.lmn` satisfies my situation.

Do I have any replacement for `$(".pqr").closests('.abc')` that give me both `.lmn` or I have to use `$.each` which I was thinking of avoiding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd target all `.abc` that has `.pqr` and then find the previous element, and filter based on the class `lmn`

```
$('.abc:has(.pqr)').prev('.lmn').css('color','red')
```

You don't have any `lmn` that are *immediate* previous element of `abc` that also contains `pqr`, so no elements match your condition.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/jz63wknh/)

Comment: Last `.pqr` also matches

Comment: Why would that match, it doesn't have an **immediate** previous sibling with the class `lmn`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function colorLmn(){
$(".pqr").closest('.abc').prevAll(".lmn").css("color", "red");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="colorLmn()">Color Lmn</button>
<div class='lmn'>                
    Prev of 1
</div>
<div class='abc'>
    1 - 1
    <div class='xyz'></div>
</div>
<div class='abc'>
1 - 2
    <div class='pqr'></div>
</div>
<div class='lmn'>
    Prev of 2
</div>
<div class='abc'>
    2 - 1
    <div class='xyz'></div>
</div>
<div class='abc'>
    2 - 2
    <div class='pqr'></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add clarification to your answer by editing it and including at least a description of what you've done in your code, and why/how it solves the problem.

Comment: $(".pqr").closests('.abc').prevAll(".lmn:first").css("color", "red");

Comment: $(".pqr").closests('.abc').prevAll(".lmn:first").css("color"‌​, "red");
gives the color red for first lmn class which is previous sibling of abc and abc has child pqr class
insted of prevAll(".lmn:first") directly use prevAll(".lmn") it will effect all lmn classes which are 
previous siblings of abc class and abc has pqr sub class
so the query is like this 
$(".pqr").closest('.abc').prevAll(".lmn").css("color", "red");